# Is backfeeding BD9C601EFJ buck converter IC a problem?

Tags: battery-charging, dc-dc-converter, buck, constant-current, topology

So I've got a circuit like that **[Values are completely random, I didn't set them yet, the question is only about topology]**:

[image]

The circuit is intended to charge a 2S battery through F3, however when the power adapter connected to VIN is unplugged the battery pack will backfeed BD9C601EFJ and I am not sure whether it is safe for the IC, so I've added a D150 Schottky diode, but of course, I don't want it because it adds inefficiencies and internal structure of IC looks like it would be safe, but I am not sure.

So, the question is: can I get rid of D150, or should I leave it?

Comment: synchronous buck converters can become boost converters when backfed. The results are not good.

Comment: Ok, thx, so I will leave the diode.